# How to add hint for an imageview

Tags: android, imageview, hint

I need to add hint text for next and previous Image View in android app,how can i do it.There is no attribute like hint in image view.
I have 2 images and need to show hint when user tries to click on those images

Comment: when exactly should the hint be shown, do you want the hint to be shown when  user clicks the image?

Comment: Hint to be shown when user is on the imageview before click.

Comment: you can use this library https://github.com/rharter/android-tooltips

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android API 14+, there is an [event for hovering](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnHoverListener.html). You can do,

```
view.setOnHoverListener(...)
```

and listen for `MotionEvent`s such as [`ACTION_HOVER_ENTER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_HOVER_ENTER) and `ACTION_HOVER_EXIT`, instead of `onLongClick`.